# Jekyll Bundle exec command on linux

Tags: localhost, jekyll, bundle

I recently started using Jekyll ... Everything went okay but when I run

```
"bundle exec jekyll serve"
```

**error** shows up but when I run `"jekyll serve"` it works...

**The error message is:**

```
" Traceback (most recent call last): 1. 
from/home/shawon/gems/bin/bundle:23:in '<main>' 
/home/shawon/gems/bin/bundle:23:in 'load': cannot load such file -- 
/usr/share/rubygems-integretion/all/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle 
(LoadError)
```

Comment: how is that `/use/share/` and not `/usr/share/` in path?

Comment: I typed it wrong